# How to make code wait while calling asynchronous calls like Ajax with returned value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've read a lot of question about this topic. But nobody has my problem.
Actualy I have this in my main code:

```
 // getHtmlInfoWindows has inside an ajax request
 var infowindowString = getHtmlInfoWindow(selectedTrucks[i], true);
 makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow[i], infowindowString, markers[i], "click");
```

Here the getHtmlInfoWindows() code

```
 $.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
})
.done(function(data) {
     // some line of code and operation
     return someData;
}
```

Basically I would to wait until getHtmlInfoWindow() finish and next execute makeInfoWindowEvent() but I don't know how.

I've tried this:

```
 $.when(infowindowString = getHtmlInfoWindow(selectedTrucks[i], true)).done(function(){}
```

but doen't work because a have to return the intere ajax response and not the single value "someData" that I want.
How can I do?

Thanks guys

Comment: `getHtmlInfoWindows()` will never return anything, no matter how long you wait.

Comment: You can make a synchronous call (calling code waits until request is completed) via jQuery ajax method this way:

    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/function",
      async: false
    }).done(function() {
      // handle result ...
    });

Note 'async' property of parameter object. Although this method is deprecated since jQuery 1.8 and should be avoided.

More details:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the code you want to be executed as a callback function:

```
// getHtmlInfoWindows has inside an ajax request

var callback = function(data){ 
   makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow[i], data, markers[i], "click"); 
}

getHtmlInfoWindow(selectedTrucks[i], true, callback);
```

and then call your callback when the ajax is done:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
})
.done(function(data) {
     // some line of code and operation
     callback(data);
}
```

Comment: Ok, it work!!! Thanks man!